# Display a page after an ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need a web page where users can modify a data already captured in database. So I made a tab with the list of every data and when a user click on one, I want to redirect the user in a page with matching data.

So this is my tab :

```
<?php

$conn_string = "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test_postgre user=postgres password='1234'";
$dbconn = pg_connect($conn_string);

$sql = "SELECT id_essai, nom_local_essai, thematique FROM public.essai";
$res = pg_query($sql) or die("Pb avec la requete: $sql");

echo'<table class="table table-hover" border="1">';
echo'<thead><tr><th>id_essai</th><th>Nom local</th><th>Thématique</th></tr></thead>';
while ($data = pg_fetch_array($res))
{

        echo'   <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a id="'.$data['id_essai'].'">
                        '.$data['id_essai'].'
                    </a></td>
                    <td>
                        '.$data['nom_local_essai'].'
                    </td>           
                    <td>
                        '.$data['thematique'].'
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>                    
        ';
    }
echo'</table>';
?>
```

And I get the ID of the data selected like this :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        var id_essai = $(this).attr('id');

        $.post('traitement_modif_essai.php',{id_essai:id_essai});
    });
});
</script>
```

Now, on the other file, I want to get the ID and display the right page, but I can't get thought.

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['id_essai'] = $_POST['id_essai'];

 echo $_SESSION['id_essai'];

 header('Location:essai_modif.php');    
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redirect the user after the session has been set by you in the PHP in the javascript callback of `post`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        var id_essai = $(this).attr('id');

        $.post('traitement_modif_essai.php',{id_essai:id_essai}, function(){
            window.location = "./essai_modif.php";
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

and in the PHP

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['id_essai'] = $_POST['id_essai'];

 echo $_SESSION['id_essai'];    
?>
```

Comment: Yep, this is what you're looking for. Nice answer